# Build curved BoxGeometry in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

i'm trying to build an curved BoxGeometry in Three.Js, but i don't know how zo build that. It should be looking like that in the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IslmE.jpg)

Heres my current code, but it's not curved yet.

`var testGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 300, 10),
     testMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xE3AA24});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use base THREE.Geometry with custom Vertices and Faces, or try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41199867/7297451