# How to add color to faces?

Tags: three.js

Im tryint to add color to a shape that i builded. I tried adding faces to the shape but im doing it wrong or i dont know how to do it. Here is a fiddle of the example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbLohvu8/.

I has follow this example of the three.js page but didnt work:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color : 0x00cc00 } );

//create a triangular geometry
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -50, -50, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  50, -50, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  50,  50, 0 ) );

//create a new face using vertices 0, 1, 2
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); //optional
var color = new THREE.Color( 0xffaa00 ); //optional
var materialIndex = 0; //optional
var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, materialIndex );

//add the face to the geometry's faces array
geometry.faces.push( face );

geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
```

Comment: If your question was answered, click the empty checkmark next to an answer to mark it correct. Otherwise, refine the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i didnt choose BoxGeometry or another material oriented at boxes, because i cant modify shape in general. How do you see in the example, is an irregular shape based in the estructure of a box. I only need the side faces and the bottom face. Finally i need add color to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, the better way to do irregular boxes or geometry is using the Shape function. Here is a update fiddle of the example using shape: http://jsfiddle.net/gbLohvu8/2/.

An example using the official documentation. More info [Here.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Shape)

```
var heartShape = new THREE.Shape();

heartShape.moveTo( 25, 25 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 25, 25, 20, 0, 0, 0 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 30, 0, 30, 35,30,35 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 30, 55, 10, 77, 25, 95 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 60, 77, 80, 55, 80, 35 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 80, 35, 80, 0, 50, 0 );
heartShape.bezierCurveTo( 35, 0, 25, 25, 25, 25 );

var extrudeSettings = 
{ amount: 8, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 2, 
steps: 2, bevelSize: 1, bevelThickness: 1 };

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( heartShape, extrudeSettings );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're building an object out of lines. If you want an object with solid faces use one of the built in primitives like [BoxGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/BoxGeometry), as in [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube).

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```